# ModifyStyle to gray out maximize-button leads to disappearing button

Tags: c++, mfc, maximize-window

I have a small application, where you can set, if maximize or minimize button is active or not/grayed out.

```
if (!m_bActiveMaximizeButton)  // Maximieren
{
    this->ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX,0,0);
    this->ModifyStyle(0,WS_CAPTION,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);       
} else
{
    this->ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION,0,0);
    this->ModifyStyle(0,WS_CAPTION,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
}
if (!m_bActiveMinimizeButton)   // Minimieren
{
    this->ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION|WS_MINIMIZEBOX,0,0);
    this->ModifyStyle(0,WS_CAPTION,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
} else
{
    this->ModifyStyle(WS_CAPTION,0,0);
    this->ModifyStyle(0,WS_CAPTION,SWP_FRAMECHANGED);
}
    CMenu* menue = this->GetSystemMenu(FALSE);

if (!m_bActiveCloseButton)  // Schließen X
{
    menue->ModifyMenu(SC_CLOSE, MF_BYCOMMAND | MF_GRAYED);
} else
{
    menue->ModifyMenu(SC_CLOSE, static_cast<UINT>(MF_BYCOMMAND | ~MF_GRAYED));
}
```

This works fine with Windows 7 styles. However, with Windows 10 styles, the buttons do not gray out, but they disappear completely. Deactivating the "Close" button does not work at all anymore.

What do I have to change to gray out the buttons again?

Comment: What's the practical difference between displaying a button a user cannot interact with and not displaying said button?

Comment: first it is more clear for the user to see, that minimize/maximize or close is deactivated.

Second: in some cases after a reload you can still click the deactivated or now not visible maximize button. If you click next to the close button it still maximizes the window, although it is not displayed.

Comment: That just re-explained the effect. But what's the *practical* consequence to a user? They cannot perform a particular operation on a window, so why display a widget that essentially just says: *"Hey, look at me, there's literally nothing you can do with me! Just letting you know."* I mean, if that property is essential to a user, they know how to open the system menu and have a look.

Comment: *"in some cases after a reload you can still click the deactivated or now not visible maximize button"* - That's a bug in your code that you need to fix.

Comment: Of course it is still usable without practical consequences. But the user would like to have it like it was before,   so I'm looking for a solution.

the bug: yes i know,  but the bug occurs since the look and feel changed,  the bug does not exist, while graying out the buttons.  So I'm first looking for a solution the user wants to have.


Is there a way to gray it out still or is this not available any more?

Comment: *"But the user would like to have it like it was before"* - If you have sustainable proof for this, then file a Design Change Request with Microsoft. If you make a convincing case it will be just a matter of time until you get what you want. I doubt that you have proof for the generalized statement or that you can make a case, seeing that you ignore usability altogether. Best to stop fighting the system.

Comment: Thanks but I don't know if you are trying to answer it or understanding the case.  Its not about changing windows.....  I'm stil asking, if I have an option as a programmer to gray out the buttons instead.  If not, I can explain it to the customer,  but at first I'm tryining to find a solution, because right now it is simply reported as a Bug from our customer (because after we changed to windows 10 look and feel the menu bar of some dialogs changed and the behavior of the close button changed as well, because you cannot deactivate it any more -  and this is in some cases necessary)

Comment: So until there is no answer that it is not possible any more to have the same behavior like before, I'm tryining o find a solution for "the problem"

Comment: *"the menu bar of some dialogs changed"* - that may or may not be a bug on your end. Impossible to tell without seeing a [mcve]. *"reported as a Bug from our customer"* - Close the report as "By design, won't fix". *"I'm stil asking, if I have an option as a programmer to gray out the buttons instead."* - Microsoft isn't exactly known to provide meaningless choices. I doubt there's an option to get the old behavior. Unless clients are ready to go back to Windows 7.